# How to implement derived classes for interfaces?

Tags: c++, interface, derived-class

I have examined a few posts but nothing seemed to cover my question.

I have an interface full of pure virtuals.
I have an implementation class of the interface which is made up from various public base classes.
Even though the methods are available at the implementation class the error says the virtuals are not implemented.

Remove the interface from the implementation and it is perfect.

Why aren't the implementation methods linked through to the interface?

Here is the code...

```
class FunctionalClass1 {
public:
    int result1(int _r) {
        return 1;
    }
    int result2(int _r) {
        return 2;
    }
};

class FunctionalClass2 {
public:
    int result3(int _r) {
        return 3;
    }
    int result4(int _r) {
        return 4;
    }
};

class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual int result1(int _r) = 0;
    virtual int result2(int _r) = 0;
    virtual int result3(int _r) = 0;
    virtual int result4(int _r) = 0;
};

class ImplementationClass1 : public FunctionalClass1, public FunctionalClass2 {
};

class ImplementationClass2 : public FunctionalClass1, public FunctionalClass2, public MyInterface {
};

    ImplementationClass1* ic1 = new ImplementationClass1(); // perfect, has all the methods available

    ImplementationClass2* ic2 = new ImplementationClass2(); // fails because interface not implemented

1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\Main.cpp(37,57): error C2259: 'ImplementationClass2': cannot instantiate abstract class
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\mainclass.h(33,7): message : see declaration of 'ImplementationClass2'
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\Main.cpp(37,57): message : due to following members:
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\Main.cpp(37,57): message : 'int MyInterface::result1(int)': is abstract
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\mainclass.h(24,14): message : see declaration of 'MyInterface::result1'
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\Main.cpp(37,57): message : 'int MyInterface::result2(int)': is abstract
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\mainclass.h(25,14): message : see declaration of 'MyInterface::result2'
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\Main.cpp(37,57): message : 'int MyInterface::result3(int)': is abstract
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\mainclass.h(26,14): message : see declaration of 'MyInterface::result3'
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\Main.cpp(37,57): message : 'int MyInterface::result4(int)': is abstract
1>X:\VisualStudioRepository\...\mainclass.h(27,14): message : see declaration of 'MyInterface::result4'
```

I do not understand by public methods of the implementation class are not linked through to the interface. It would be nice if someone could explain why it fails. It would be great if someone could provide a solution.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: You're inheriting MyInterface which contains virtual methods that need to be implemented .

Comment: Why do you think they should be linked? Overriding only works on classes that inherit from each other.

Comment: `FunctionalClass1` and `FunctionalClass2` do not inherit from `MyInterface` so can't override the pure methods,

Comment: Start using the `override` specifier (instead of or combined with `virtual`) when you _think_ you are overriding. It would have caught this mistake directly.

Comment: Guys, it's not about a typo. OP thought it should work (I guess because the signatures are the same?) and they don't understand why it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you want would be to have `FunciontalClass1` and `FunctionalClass2` implement `MyInterface`:

```
class FunctionalClass1 : public virtual MyInterface {
public:
    int result1(int _r) override {
        return 1;
    }
    int result2(int _r) override {
        return 2;
    }
};

class FunctionalClass2 : public virtual MyInterface{
public:
    int result3(int _r) override {
        return 3;
    }
    int result4(int _r) override {
        return 4;
    }
};

class ImplementationClass2 : public FunctionalClass1, public FunctionalClass2 {
};
```

Note that these classes will now be abstract because they have un-implemented virtual methods. Also `MyInterface` needs to be virtually inherited so that `ImplementationClass2` only gets a single `MyInterface` parent.

Another option is to provide overrides in `ImplementationClass2` that delegate to `FunctionalClass1` and `FunctionalClass2`:

```
class ImplementationClass2 : public FunctionalClass1, public FunctionalClass2, public MyInterface {
public:
    int result1(int _r) override {
        return FunctionalClass1::result1(_r);
    }
    int result2(int _r) override {
        return FunctionalClass1::result2(_r);
    }
    int result3(int _r) override {
        return FunctionalClass2::result3(_r);
    }
    int result4(int _r) override {
        return FunctionalClass2::result4(_r);
    }
};
```

Comment: An extra detail could be to separate the interface class into two separate interfaces (and keep the `virtual` inheritance) which would also make the functional classes non-abstract (as they were in OPs code but for the wrong reason).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I have gone for the latter as the functional classes are used across a number of implementations so the former would get a bit messy, as well as not adhereing to clean architecture principles. I ommitted "override" as I am not sure that actually does anything. So to conclude with clarity, even though the derived class has all of the public methods of the interface via base classes they still need to be declared in the derived class, requiring a call to the method of the particular base class. Meaning, no direct overriding of the interface pure virtuals via base classes.

Comment: `override` just says that a method is intended to override a base class virtual method. If the method declared as `override` does not in fact override a method, then you'll get a compiler error. This is very useful as it will catch mistakes in the name or parameters of the method that would cause it to not actually override like you wanted.

I hope that made sense.